# change the state of a toggle switch without reloading page in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, ajax

Im working with a friend on a project that some one else did the backend coding along with a bit of front end.
im trying to save the state of a toggle switch in local storage and at the same time prevent the page from reloading every time I toggle.

```
function App() {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState("")
    const [time, setTime] = useState("")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState("")

    const history = useNavigate();
    
    let redirect = ""
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const userToggle = useSelector(state => state.toggle)

    const {error, loading} = userToggle

    let token = null
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")

        if(userInfo){
            token = "Bearer " + JSON.parse(userInfo).token
        }else{
            redirect = "/"
            history(redirect)
        }

        async function getToggleInfo(){
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": token
                }
            }
            
            await axios.get("/api/users/toggle/", config).then((response) => {
                if(response.data){
                    a = new Date(response.data.toggled_time)
                    setToggle(response.data.is_toggled)
                    
                }else if(!localStorage.getItem("userInfo")){
                    redirect = "/"
                    history(redirect)
                }else{
                    redirect = "/new-user"
                    history(redirect)
                }
                
            })
        }
        
        let a = null

        getToggleInfo()

        if(time<10){
            setLimit(false)
            setToggle(toggle)
        }

        setInterval(() => {
            let b = new Date()
            let def = Math.round((b-a)/60000)
            setTime(String(def))

        }, 1000);

    }, [limit])

    const toggleHandler = (checked) => {
        if(time < 0 ){
            setLimit(true)
            setMessage("For your goodness and our database, stay on your mood at least 10 minutes ;)")
        }else{
            setTime(0)
            var bool = 0
            setToggle(checked)
            if(toggle === ""){
                bool = 1
            }else if(toggle == true){
                bool = 0
            }else{
                bool = 1
            }
            const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo")).id
            dispatch(sendToggle(userId, bool))
            **window.location.reload(false)**
        }
  }
```

me being a noob, cant really figure out how to write this is react and change the state with out reloadig the page.

Comment: Remove `window.location.reload(false)`. You should almost never reload the page with react

Comment: I know, I'm looking for an alternative. if I remove it the toggle doesn't move anymore because the previous state hasn't been logged yet

Comment: That means you have some design flaws because react should automatically update everything without reloading. You didn't include the jsx part of the component, maybe the error is there.